# How to mix Laravel Routing with Vue routing?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

I plan to write a project where I will use Laravel and Vue, I wonder how much it is possible to use Vue Routing with Laravel Routing, Exactly I want my App behaves like SPA application, but sometimes I want to use Laravel routing, for example for Registration and Authentication, I am trying to avoid JWT validation, After a long search on the internet I could not find the perfect answer, I wonder how programmatically correct this decision is? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're not separating the Vue frontend from the Laravel backend and building it all in Laravel, then I'd highly suggest [checking out Inertia](https://inertiajs.com/) which couples the 2 frameworks seamlessly in a perfect SPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jetstream laravel with inertia js](https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/stacks/inertia.html) to get a SPA with laravel routing.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30998121)